# angular js ng-model inside ng-repeat not accessible in function outside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I am repeating ng-repeat for dropdown list selected item times.when i am going to access ng-model which is inside of ng-repeat on click function of button which is outside the ng-repeat i haven't get value of ng-model .it shows undefined .

```
<div data-ng-repeat="R in RespPerson">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="_tblrating" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px">
        <tr class="_labeltr">
            <td>
                <span>Productivitiy </span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span>Quality </span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span>Cost </span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span>Delivery </span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span>Safety </span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span>Environment </span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span>Technology </span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span>Aesthetics </span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span>RPN NO </span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span>Categorisation of Problem </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input id="txtProductivitiy" type="text" ng-bind="obj1=R.Productivitiy" ng-model="R.Productivitiy" class="numericOnly " />
           {{obj1}}
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="txtQuality" type="text" ng-model="R.Quality" class="numericOnly " />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="txtCost" type="text" ng-model="R.Cost" class="numericOnly " />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="txtDelivery" type="text" ng-model="R.Delivery " class="numericOnly " />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="txtSafety" type="text" ng-model="R.Safety" class="numericOnly " />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="txtEnvironment" type="text" ng-model="R.Environment" class="numericOnly " />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="txtTechnology" type="text" ng-model="R.Technology" class="numericOnly " />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="txtAesthetics" type="text" ng-model="R.Aesthetics " class="numericOnly " />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="txtRPNNO" type="text" class="numericOnly" value="{{R.Productivitiy + R.Quality}}" disabled="disabled" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="txtCategorisationProblem" disabled="disabled" type="text" value="{{funCategorisationProblem()}}" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<input id="btnsave" type="button" value="Save" class="btn" ng-click="btnsave()" />
<script>    
    app.controller('spController', function ($scope, $http) {

       $scope.ddlprocessOwnerChange = function () {
       $scope.RespPerson = $scope.ddlprocessowner;
    };

    $scope.btnsave = function () {
      alert($scope.R.Productivitiy);
    };
  }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's expected. R is only set in the ng-repeat scope, and represents the person for the **current** (of several) iteration.

Your code is basically equivalent of

```
var RespPerson;

function displayAll() {
    for (R in RespPerson) {
        // display R
    }
}

function save() {
    alert(R); 
}
```

You see that the above code can't possibly work. R is only known inside the for loop of the first function.

What you can do, though, is pass the current person as argument to your function:

```
$scope.btnsave = function (R) {
  alert(R.Productivitiy);
};
```

and inside the view:

```
ng-click="btnsave(R)"
```

But of course, once again, the button must be **inside** the ng-repeat: each person must have its own save button, and R is only available inside the ng-repeat. If it's outside, which of the many persons would the button save?

Answer (score 0):

It is a basic. In any language we do not try to access a loop/iterator variable outside of the iteration.

Here you are iterating

```
data-ng-repeat="R in RespPerson"
```

Means for each RespPerson iteration one Variable will be create as R and will be used for that iteration only. Not for the next iteration. So after iteration complete the variable is not there in the scope.

Now when you use

```
alert($scope.R.Productivitiy);
```

In your button event code. R is not there any more.
You should use

```
$scope.RespPerson[index] //index is which you want.
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for giving your valuable time.
finally got answer :)

here is working code

```
<div data-ng-repeat="R in RespPerson">
            <fieldset class="info-box-gradient">
                <legend>{{R.Title}} </legend>
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr class="_hdr">
                        <td>
                            <span>Root Cause Analysis </span>
                            <div class="_note">
                                Tick
                                <input id="Checkbox1" type="checkbox" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" />
                                to add Cause to Summary of Root Cause analysis
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="_labeltr" style="padding: 0px;">
                        <td>
                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <span>Man</span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <span>Material </span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <span>Method </span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <span>Machine </span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <span>Environment </span>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <input id="chkman1" type="checkbox" ng-model="chkman[R.id]" />
                                        <textarea id="txtman1" cols="20" rows="2" ng-model="txtman[R.id]"></textarea>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input id="chkMaterial1" type="checkbox" ng-model="chkMaterial[R.id]" />
                                        <textarea id="txtMaterial1" cols="20" rows="2" ng-model="txtMaterial[R.id]"></textarea>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input id="chkMethod1" type="checkbox" ng-model="chkMethod[R.id]" />
                                        <textarea id="txtMethod1" cols="20" rows="2" ng-model="txtMethod[R.id]"></textarea>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input id="chkMachine1" type="checkbox" ng-model="chkMachine[R.id]" />
                                        <textarea id="txtMachine1" cols="20" rows="2" ng-model="txtMachine[R.id]"></textarea>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input id="chkEnvironment1" type="checkbox" ng-model="chkEnvironment[R.id]" />
                                        <textarea id="txtEnvironment1" cols="20" rows="2" ng-model="txtEnvironment[R.id]"></textarea>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="_hdr">
                        <td>
                            <span>Rating </span>
                            <div class="_note">
                                ( 1 is lowest & 5 is Highest)
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding: 0px">
                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="_tblrating" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px">
                                <tr class="_labeltr">
                                    <td>
                                        <span>Productivitiy </span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <span>Quality </span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <span>Cost </span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <span>Delivery </span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <span>Safety </span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <span>Environment </span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <span>Technology </span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <span>Aesthetics </span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <span>RPN NO </span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <span>Categorisation of Problem </span>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <input id="txtProductivitiy" type="text" ng-model="Productivitiy[R.id]" class="numericOnly " />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input id="txtQuality" type="text" ng-model="Quality[R.id]" class="numericOnly " />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input id="txtCost" type="text" ng-model="Cost[R.id]" class="numericOnly " />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input id="txtDelivery" type="text" ng-model="Delivery[R.id]" class="numericOnly " />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input id="txtSafety" type="text" ng-model="Safety[R.id]" class="numericOnly " />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input id="txtEnvironment" type="text" ng-model="Environment[R.id]" class="numericOnly " />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input id="txtTechnology" type="text" ng-model="Technology[R.id]" class="numericOnly " />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input id="txtAesthetics" type="text" ng-model="Aesthetics[R.id]" class="numericOnly " />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input id="txtRPNNO" type="text" class="numericOnly" value="{{funRPNNO(R.id)}}" disabled="disabled" />
                                        <input id="txtRPNTotal" type="text" ng-model="RPNTotal[R.id]" class="numericOnly" ng-show="False" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input id="txtCategorisationProblem" disabled="disabled" type="text" value="{{funCategorisationProblem(R.id)}}" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <span>Corrective action(CA) </span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <span>Preventive action (PA) </span>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <textarea id="txtCorrectiveaction" cols="20" rows="2" ng-model="txtCorrectiveaction[R.id]"></textarea>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <textarea id="txtPreventiveaction" cols="20" rows="2" ng-model="txtPreventiveaction[R.id]"></textarea>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <span>Effectiveness </span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <span>Target </span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <span>Actual Date </span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <span>Review Date </span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <span>Status of CA </span>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <textarea id="txtEffectiveness" cols="20" rows="2" ng-model="txtEffectiveness[R.id]"></textarea>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input id="txtTarget" type="text" ng-model="txtTarget[R.id]" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input id="txtActualDate" type="text" ng-model="txtActualDate[R.id]" datepicker />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input id="txtReviewDate" type="text" ng-model="txtReviewDate[R.id]" datepicker />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <select id="txtStatusofCA" ng-model="txtStatusofCA[R.id]">
                                            <option selected="selected">Pending</option>
                                            <option>Implemented</option>
                                            <option>Non-Implemented</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
<input id="btnsave" type="button" value="Save" class="btn" ng-click="btnsave()" />

<script>   
$scope.Productivitiy = {};
    $scope.Quality = {};
    $scope.Cost = {};
    $scope.Delivery = {};
    $scope.Safety = {};
    $scope.Environment = {};
    $scope.Technology = {};
    $scope.Aesthetics = {};
    $scope.RPNTotal = {};

    app.controller('spController', function ($scope, $http) {

       $scope.ddlprocessOwnerChange = function () {
       $scope.RespPerson = $scope.ddlprocessowner;
    };

    $scope.btnsave = function () {
      alert($scope.Productivitiy);//get all ng-model value of "Productivitiy" return array
    };
  }
 </script>
```